# Tampermonkey - add page using non-existing URL

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm creating a userscript which adds new functions to a website.
The website has many users, but doesn't have a feature to search for users.
I want to create such a function. To do that, I have created a button in the already existing search page for other search purposes. When I click the button, I need the script to search for the input on Google and fetch the URLs and show the results in a piece of HTML code on a non-existing page.

Can I fake an URL with a userscript, so that it uses it to show HTML?

If not, can I replace certain HTML within the page?

The code isn't really that interesting. It just adds a button with a link and selects it when on the non-existing page.

**CODE:**

```
if (document.URL == "http://www.bierdopje.com/search" || document.URL == "http://www.bierdopje.com/search/" || window.location.href.indexOf("search/shows") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("search/episodes") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("search/forum") > -1) {
var users = document.createElement('li');
users.setAttribute('class', 'strong');
var UsersNode = document.createTextNode("Gebruikers");
var UsersLink = document.createElement('a');
UsersLink.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.bierdopje.com/search/users/');

document.getElementById("submenu").childNodes[1].appendChild(users).appendChild(UsersLink).appendChild(UsersNode);

if (window.location.href.indexOf("search/users/") > -1) {
    UsersLink.setAttribute('href', './');
    UsersLink.setAttribute('class', 'selected');
}
}
```

Comment: This question is currently unclear and probably "Too localized". Complete [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
Make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and/or post the actual HTML versus desired HTML.

Comment: You're probably right. Fortunately I solved my own problem. Thanks anyway for reading the question.

Comment: You should better create an extension for your browser.
It isn't as complicated as it looks. With this, you can run Javascript functions in a HTML window popping out of the extension.<br>
See https://justinribeiro.github.io/chrome-extensions-codelab-gdg-oakdale/images/screenshot-20150108-step-02-blank-popup-loaded.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but like Brock Adams already said: it may have been too localized.
The solution to fake an url is to replace the 404 not found content.

If there's like a container with a header and a paragraph, find the container by making it a variable, and then replace it with another variable:

```
// find the container
var example = document.getElementById('container').childNodes[0];

// set new container
var newcontainer = document.createElement('div');
newcontainer.setAttribute('id', 'ncontainer');

// replace the existing container with the new one
example.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, example);

// write content to the new container
document.getElementById('ncontainer').innerHTML ='<p>This is not a 404 anymore</p>';
```

There are probably a lot more and shorter ways to accomplish this, but they can be found by Google (javascript replace).

To replace the complete page, use

```
document.write()
```

To finish the page, you can set the title with the following:

```
document.title = "WEBSITE TITLE";
```